# My sql select is updating when updating a form

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table of companies, I send a query to the database and get the companies I want to call. The query is ordered by when I have to call before NOW(). I get the query in $_SESSION.

```
SELECT * FROM empresa WHERE (fase = 'Lead' AND resultado != 'Revisar' AND proximocontacto < NOW()) ORDER BY `proximocontacto` DESC LIMIT 100
```

Then I go to other page that goes through the array and shows it to me. You have each company with a form and can change values and then updates when it has changed anything with a $_POST.
When the update is not important its ok, but when you change the time to call to tomorrow for example, that company dissapears from the list, like I had called the first page again, but I didn't. Not sure how its updating really.

```
$empresas = array();
$numero = 0;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            foreach ($row as $value=>$contenido){
                $empresas[$numero][$value]= $contenido;
            }
    $numero+=1;
$_SESSION['empresa']= $empresas;
```

Tried just assigning

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $array_row=$row;
}
$_SESSION['empresa']= $array_row;
```

But the result is the same.

PS: Maybe it's not clear, when I receive the query I stored it as global and then went to another page, then I go through the array and update some companies with update, but never query select again, so even when I change date, that shouldn't affect my array because it's in SESSION, or there's something I'm getting wrong.

Comment: Chances are that the company disappearing from the list is not having a date that matches tomorrow.

Have you tried doing a `var_dump($result)` on both versions of the query to see what's returned?

Comment: You are querying for anything that is < now(), are you querying to find anything that is > now as tomorrow's date would not return with the query you have

Comment: you know they invented AJAX to simplify your architecture, do you :-)